# How To: Save JMeterVariable values to influxdb with the sampleresults

Tags: variables, jmeter, influxdb

I'd like to store some JMeterVariables together with the sampleResults to an influxdb using a BackendListenerClient for influxdb (I am using package rocks.nt.apm.jmeter to get the raw results).

My current test logs in for a random customer requests some random entities and logs out. Most of the results are within a range, I'd like to zoom in to certain extreme sample results, find out for which customer / requested entity these results are. We have seen in the past we can find performance issues with specific configurations this way.

I store customer and entity ID in a variable. My issue is that the JMeterVariables are not accessible from the BackendListenerClient. I looked at the sample_variables property, but this property will store the variables in the sampleEvent, which is not accessible in the BackendListener.

I could use the threadName, or sample label to store the vars, but I saw the CSVwriter can actually write the var values from the event, which is a much nicer solution.

Looking forward on your thoughts,

Best regards, Spud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get it right - the Backend Listener is not customizable in terms of fine-shaping the data you're sending to Influx.
Alas.

However, there's a Swiss Army Knife always available in JMeter: the JSR223 components.
The [JSR223 listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener), in your case.

The [InfluxDB line protocol](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/write_protocols/line_protocol_tutorial/) is simple as simple could be, the HTTP/Rest libraries are 
in abundance *([Apache HTTP](https://hc.apache.org/) must have been already included with standard JMeter, to my recollection, no additional jars needed)* - just pick it all up, form your timeseries as you like, toss it towards your InfluxDB REST endpoint, job's done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, which confirms my suspicions. 

I do like the suggestion to use the JSR223 listener, however will probably use it to add the thread vars in the threadname, which I think is less error prone (or do you see any issues with that approach?).

I still think its odd this data is not available for the Backend Listener.